# Why does SET ROWCOUNT not reset after GO?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql) for `SCOPE_IDENTITY`:

> A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same
>   stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.

According to [SQL Server Utilities Statements - GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go):

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code
>   editor. SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should
>   send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of
>   SQL Server.
>
> The current batch of statements is composed of all
>   statements entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc
>   session or script if this is the first GO.

Armed with that information I wrote (in SMSS) this T-SQL:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1    -- Limit to 1 row returned

-- Returns 1 row as expected
SELECT *
FROM MyTable

GO -- Batch ends

-- Still returns one row
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```

From my understanding `SET ROWCOUNT` (I know it is deprecated in DML but not SELECTs) is scoped to its module (from what I have seen examining other posts at any rate).

My questions:

1. Is `SET ROWCOUNT` an exception to the 'module' rule mentioned above?
2. Is it NOT scoped to the module at all?
3. Is there a more complete definition of T-SQL scope?

I ran a query, then a stored procedure, that only sets rowcount to 4 (I picked 4 out of the blue) and then ran query again: so

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
EXE MySproc 
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

...returns all rows then 4 rows then all rows again so it is definitely scoped to at least sprocs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most (all?) `set` statements take effect at the session level; from [SET Statements (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql):

> provides several SET statements that change the current session handling

---

Quite a few of those `set` statements listed @ that link are obviously session-level settings, eg:

- `set dateformat`
- `set fips_flagger`
- `set indentity_insert`
- `set statistics time/io`
- `set nocount`
- `set transaction isolation level`

And by session-level I mean that they remain in place across batches/`go` statements.